# Installing lablgtk on Windows for OCaml GUI

Tags: ocaml, lablgtk

I'm having trouble installing lablgtk in order to create a GUI for my Ocaml program. Not only am I finding the instructions on the site difficult to follow but I am having trouble finding the packages online to download; my browser is blocking most of the sites as it says they are dangerous.

What is the easiest, most straightforward way to download and install lablgtk?

Comment: Just a remark, lablgtk is still one of the most reliable ways to develop cross-OS GUIs in OCaml, but it is (as far as I know) no longer actively developed. It is still well maintained and patched regularly, but shouldn't have new features (such as Gtk3). For a mid- to long-term project, I would recommend another framework. If it's mostly for learning or for a small code base, however, lablgtk should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow Jonathan's instructions [1] and install `opam` with `depext cygwin` [2]. Then it should be easy to install `lablgtk2` on Windows.

- [1] : http://protz.github.io/ocaml-installer/
- [2] : https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/

Comment: Yes, lablgtk can be installed with https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/ and `opam install depext depext-cygwinports && opam depext -i lablgtk`. But don't use http://protz.github.io/ocaml-installer/. It's not fully compatible with https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/

Comment: Thank you both for your response. I am definitely on the right track now, though I am having a problem with GTK+. When Cygwin starts to install lablgtk, I eventually get an error saying "GTK+ is required". The troubleshooting says "This package requires gtk+ 2.0 development packages installed on your system".
I have now installed libgtk2.0-devel  and libgtk2.0_0 by re-running the Cygwin setup (setup-x86.exe), but I get the same error when I try to install lablgtk again. The cygwin64 folder in my directory contains a folder "gtk-2.0" in the "lib" folder. I'm not sure which step to take next.

Comment: I had a similar issue which was due to `pkg-config`. You have to install pkg-config and set the variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to something like `/usr/x86_64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/pkgconfig`.

Comment: I am wondering if my issue is that pkg-config isn't installed correctly. Every time I try to install lablgtk, Cygwin first outputs the following `# The following system packages are needed:

#  - gtk2.0

#  - pkg-config

installed:gtk2.0

installed:pkg-config`
Then when it fails it outputs this:
`[ERROR] The compilation of lablgtk failed at "./configure --prefix
        C:/Users/myname/Documents/.opam/4.02.3+mingw64c
        LABLGLDIR=C:/Users/myname/Documents/.opam/4.02.3+mingw64c/lib/lablgl".`

Comment: You have to install depext-cygwinports (as mentioned above). It will install a wrapper for pkg-config, setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH should not be necessary. And you have to add /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin to your PATH ( as mentioned here https://github.com/fdopen/opam-repository-mingw/#things-to-remember or in the output of `opam install depext depext-cygwinports` )

Comment: I followed rafix's suggestion of adding to the PATH. It has successfully installed, now I just need to test that it runs as expected. Thank you all for your advice!